# Validation function not working rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I'm using a devise user model (with rails 4). Here is my current user model. What I want is a validation that doesn't allow for the :super_admin to be true at the same time that :admin is false. Here is the current version of the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validate :if_super_admin_then_must_be_admin

  def if_super_admin_then_must_be_admin
    if :super_admin && !:admin
      errors.add(:admin, "can't be false if :super_admin is true.")
    end
  end
end
```

My rspec test for this fails, the model can be valid if :super_admin is true and :admin is false. I double checked it using console, so the problem isn't in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
def if_super_admin_then_must_be_admin
  if self.super_admin? && !self.admin?
    errors.add(:admin, "can't be false if :super_admin is true.")
  end
end
```